# How to insert big chunk of data into db?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-3, nopcommerce

I am using [nopcommerce](http://www.nopcommerce.com/) and [arvixe](http://www.arvixe.com/) hosting.

I have a xml file that contains all the products for my site (about 26000 records). I wrote a plugin that allows me to add records using sql script.

The problem is: 
Time of request ends and only first 500 - 1000 records appears in db. What would you recommend?  Maybe I should move my code to different place (not in plugin)?

Comment: How are you adding the data values at present ? Have you profiled the database ?

Comment: you cannot realistically run a long running process like this using standard HTTP. HTTP has a timeout. Write a windows app or call the server asynchronously.

Comment: I am adding data value as described. I can show you a code if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx):

```
using (SqlConnection destinationConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    destinationConnection.Open();

    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection))
    {
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.BulkCopyDemoMatchingColumns";
        try
        {
            // The reader is a SqlDataReader which has all 26000 records
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```